# Is "steepness" a proper word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a marketing writer and am working on a product description, which would be as follows:

> We track cool metrics like location, duration, speed and steepness.

Is that use of the word correct?  Any insight would be wonderful.

Comment: _Cool_ metrics?  While you're editing, you might want to change that word, too.  Consider _useful_, _informative_, or _interesting_ instead.

Comment: Just don't use *stepth*.

Comment: @J.R.  Oh, I don't know. Sounds like a typical elevator pitch to me.

Comment: There are no "cool" metrics. Especially not location or duration.

Comment: Temperature could be cool

Comment: General Reference. Of course it's a word, except in the context of tracked *metrics* you'd probably refer to **gradient** (and you probably wouldn't call *metrics* "cool").

Comment: @GEdgar: I dunno, I rather like that. :)

Answer (score 7):

I humbly suggest *degree of incline* or just *[slope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_%28slope%29)*:

> The grade (also called slope, incline, gradient, pitch or rise) of a
>   physical feature, topographic landform or constructed element, refers
>   to the amount of inclination of that surface to the horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

*Grade* is what they call it in civil engineering and by bicyclists.

[Article about San Francisco hills and grades](http://humofthecity.com/2012/02/04/san-francisco-hills-and-grades/)

Comment: But the word may not be familiar to people outside those fields.

Comment: Or inside them. I trained as a civil engineer (many years ago now) and it took me ages to realise what a "grade-separated junction" actually meant. *Gradient* is a better word in the OP's context.

Comment: I'm betting that someone who would buy something that 'tracks cool metrics' would know the word *grade.* I respectfully disagree that *gradient* is a better word. *Gradient* has so many other meanings in mathematics and biology. Even when you look up *gradient* in Wikipedia it says "For the measure of steepness of a road, see Grade."

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see why *steepness* shouldn't be treated as a valid word. It's basic sense is: how steep something is.  It is not necessarily asking the degree of incline, or the type of slope.  The primary sense is how much an object possesses the quality of being steep.

The OED also defines it as such:

> The quality or condition of being steep.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption here, but it sounds like this might be used to explain some kind of software that can track a person's movements in some way or another?

If that's the case, then maybe *altitude* would work? Because if you track movement and the altitude changes over time, then you will likely be able to calculate the *steepness* (which is also a valid word) between two points.